# How can I edit contacts at Skype iPad version?

Tags: ipad, skype

It just seems nonsense that you can't edit contacts at Skype iPad version, I know less is more, but perhaps too less is *actually* less.

So how can you edit contacts at Skype iPad version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that it is **currently not possible** to edit contacts in Skype for iPad.

This Skype KB article mentions viewing and deleting contacts, but makes no mention of editing contacts. This is in contrast to the related articles for other systems such as Windows/Mac that does mention editing contacts.

- [How do I manage my contacts in Skype for iPad?](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA12238/how-do-i-manage-my-contacts-in-skype-for-ipad)

In addition, this Skype Community thread asks the question and is met by a moderator's response mentioning that it is not possible:

- [Skype for iPad/Editing Contacts](http://community.skype.com/t5/iOS-iPhone-and-iPad/Skype-for-iPad-Editing-Contacts/td-p/181380)

Answer (score 1):

Skype contacts can be add and removed in the Skype iPad application. You can add a contact by adding them in a menu, removing a contact can be done on the same way to remove an application (Keep your finger on a contact in your home Skype screen for several seconds, then use the cross on the right top of the contact).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. In Skype you click on the contact then click on the down arrow under their name on the top. A menu drops down, click on view profile and scroll down to the bottom to delete or block and delete.
Hope this helps everyone

Answer (score -1):

There is that can be done to fix this; it is up to Skype's software engineers to implement that feature..